# Tailwind installation with react in ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

i have this error during the installation of tailwind installation with react
the error is this :

```
npm i tailwind postcss autoprefixer
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'amqplib@0.5.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <=9' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.16.1', npm: '9.8.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 153 packages, and audited 395 packages in 14s

88 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

14 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 7 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.


Run `npm audit` for details
```

please help if you any idea.
thanks in advance

Comment: try to downgrade node version to 16 using nvm

Answer (score 1):

`Tailwind` hasn't been updated in the last four years, and it relies on the `amqplib` library version 0.5.2, which hasn't been updated in the last six years. Considering the lack of recent updates/

it is recommended to explore alternative solutions.